# How to fix InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a zip file from url, but I get the below warning

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'www.ons.gov.uk'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

I read about this a bit and most of the threads revolves around how to disable it (if you know what you are doing) and the general concept as a whole. From what I understood, isn't `request` library capable of performing **certificate validation** by **default**? Why should I make a secured request to a open source file? I am exposing myself to something here, and how can I fix this ?

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zipfile import ZipFile
import io

url = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fhousing%2fdatasets%2fukhousebuildingpermanentdwellingsstartedandcompleted%2fcurrent/ukhousebuilding.zip"


response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, verify=False)
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as myzip:
    with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as hfile:
        df = pd.read_csv(hfile)

print(df)
```

Apparently this warning only turns up when I use `verify=False`, shouldn't it actually prevent this warning?

Sorry for asking too many questions, but I am trying to understand what's happening here. Please correct me if I have misunderstood the concept.

Comment: The `requests` module verifies SSL certificates. Do not use `verify=False`, & as you said there will be no warming. I cannot currently think of any reason why you'd want to avoid SSL cert verification.

Comment: Setting `verify=None` removed these warnings for me.

Comment: I'd like to add a clarifying question: is this error pertaining to not finding the appropriate root cert (or part of the chain) for verification?

Comment: @mechanical_meat if you cannot find a way to connect to a server due to SSL certificate validation error, then it's useful

Answer (score 7):

> From what I understood, isn't request library capable of performing certificate validation by default?

Yes, it does.

> Why should I make a secured request to a open source file?

For security reasons. You want to be sure you actually get the file you expect, from the source you request it from without any manipulations to the file.

> I am exposing myself to something here, and how can I fix this?

Yes, you are. Remove the `verify=False` parameter.

> Apparently this warning only turns up when I use verify=False, shouldn't it actually prevent this warning?

No, it's exactly what causes the warning. Read it carefully. It warns you about unverified HTTPS requests. The request is unverified because you specified it.

**TL;DR**

If the requests works without the `verify=False` parameter, you should not use it.
Otherwise you should still not use it and find another solution.

Comment: "You want to be sure you actually get the file you expect, from the source you request it from without any manipulations to the file." What other security risks are there, aside from possibly getting a different response? In my use case, it doesn't matter if I get a different response.

Comment: There are many reasons. I cannot give you a exhaustive list. If you don't care about the response the only reason to send a request is sending data of some kind. Obviously the data you send can also be manipulated. Also all the traffic in both directions can be observed.

Comment: Indeed, I am sending data. It is not at all obvious to me that my data can be manipulated, or that traffic in both directions can be observed, since I don't know how certificate verification works. Would you be able to recommend some resources (e.g. books) on how certificate verification works?

Comment: No, sorry I don't know any books and that's a really broad topic. I just had IT-Security as a course in my Computer Science Masters degree, but explaining such topics in a comment on SO is kinda hard. I'll try my best though. The the 'S' in HTTPS is for secure, it is no longer secure if you do not check the certificates, as they are what makes it secure. HTTPS works with hybrid cryptography (asymmetric cryptography + symmetric cryptography) the certificate part of the in the asymmetric half. I believe Wikipedia is a good enough resource if you want to dig into the topic.

Comment: Your browser or operating system has a list of so root certificates preinstalled. They belong to certificate authorities (CAs). These certificate authorities can issue and sign certificates to other entities (e.g. websites) thus your browser can trust a lot of websites certificates. The certificates hold a cryptographic key for your communication and also hold information on the partner of your communication, thus if you encrypt your data using that key you should be confident that only the entity you address can actually decrypt and read your data.

Answer (score 1):

`requests` does certificate verification by default on it's own. You have explicitly instructed the library not to do so with `verify=False`, hence the warning.

You should protect the data transfer as much as possible even in times you might consider requested resources as public. Without proper TLS/SSL validation a man-in-the-middle attacker can intercept your connection. Interception might yield various results:

- attacker might learn about your communication -- breach of confidentiality
- attacker might change the contents of the fetched data -- breach of integrity.

Depending on the code using the fetched data, the attacker might be able to influence it's execution and in worst case he/she might try to leverage a security vulnerability in the processing code to achieve your computing system compromise (ultimately a remote code execution).